# How to set language based on user profile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

i was able to create translation for my project. I inserted code to have browser to remember users selected language, however, when i switch to another devise, or phone or when my app sends out emails, it defaults to the english language. So how can i have user select language, in profile, so it will remember selected language in outgoing emails? I am using devise

my application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  if cookies[:educator_locale] && I18n.available_locales.include?(cookies[:educator_locale].to_sym)
    l = cookies[:educator_locale].to_sym
  else
    l = I18n.default_locale
    cookies.permanent[:educator_locale] = l
  end
  I18n.locale = l
end
end
```

my config.ru part

```
get '/change_locale/:locale', to: 'settings#change_locale', as: :change_locale
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently just using the cookie to keep track of the selected locale, a different device or browser will have its own cookies so they fall back to the default.

You have to persist the selected locale for a user on the server side (user profile) and then check in the `ApplicationController` if you have a logged in user (devise provides helpers as far as I recall) and if so set the `I18.locale` to this stored value otherwise you can just fall back to your current cookie based solution (for not logged in users).

Another (fallback) approach is to guess the locale by the browser specific headers which will be sent with the request. Say if the browser locale is set to french the user might also want to see the content in french.

Comment: something like this?<% if user_signed_in? %>
            <%= set_locale %>
 <% end %>

Comment: `I18n.locale = current_user.preferred_locale if user_signed_in?` where preferred_locale is a persistent field of your user model